# ajax localhost cors error

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to write this application on my localhost - in javascript but I am getting cross domain errors - how can I get the value of bitcoin every second and ensure it works locally.

```
                $.ajax({
                      url: "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD",
                      dataType: 'json',
                      crossDomain : true,
                      success: function(data){
                        callback(data);
                      }
                });
```

Comment: you could try using `jsonp`

Comment: I tried that. - still get an error 429

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2fska0jo/ demo1

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2fska0jo/1/ demo2 -- with jsonp

Comment: You could consider running a local webserver. Something lightweight like node.js or simply spin up a MVC site in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well - its a basic demo - I just wish to get the application working locally

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are executing that call multiple times since that error is due to Too Many requests sometimes.

I would try executing the call only once to see if it works.

I tried the same ajax call in a html page running from my local machine (no web server) and it worked fine.

Make sure also that you are not banned somehow :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2fska0jo/4/ - even if I make the calls further apart - still get an error

Comment: Is there any chance you can post all the relevant code?

Comment: Well I mean that is it - in a nutshell - but the full app I am building is here - and that seems to be the biggest issue so far -- https://jsfiddle.net/g48ckukd/